# Add object to array inside parse.com query

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform, javascript-objects

I'm having a bit of a strange problem.

I need to add objects to an array, and using the normal `array.push(object)` doesn't seem to work (nothing is pushed).

The pushes happen both inside and outside for-loops in parse.com queries.

I've tried some debugging, and console.log on all steps return the results as I expect.

**My question is**: Is there something I don't know about how parse.com queries work in connection to array.push, or maybe for-loops? Any help would be appreciated.

The particulars are entities (array) and entity (object).

I'd expect a result something like:

```
entities = [
    { url: '/first', changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 1.0 },
    { url: '/second', changefreq: 'monthly', priority: 0.9 },
    { url: '/third', changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.5 }
];
```

But I only get the very first push to appear in the array.

I've checked all the parse.com queries, and they do return the data I need and use in the example below.

My code:

```js
module.exports = {
  getSitemap: function(callback) {
    "use strict";
    var Page = Parse.Object.extend('Page'),
      pageQuery = new Parse.Query(Page),
      Article = Parse.Object.extend('Article'),
      articleQuery = new Parse.Query(Article),
      Profile = Parse.Object.extend('Profile'),
      profileQuery = new Parse.Query(Profile),
      Category = Parse.Object.extend('Category'),
      categoryQuery = new Parse.Query(Category),
      entities = [],
      entity = {},
      i,
      sitemap;

    entity.url = '/';
    entity.changefreq = 'weekly';
    entity.priority = 1.0;
    entities.push(entity);
    entity = {};

    articleQuery.equalTo('published', true);
    articleQuery.select("permalink");
    articleQuery.find().then(function(results) {
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
        entity.url = '/article/' + results[i].get('permalink');
        entity.changefreq = 'monthly';
        entity.priority = 0.9;
        entities.push(entity);
        entity = {};
      }
    }, function(error) {
      // do nothing
    });

    pageQuery.select("pagePermaLink");
    pageQuery.find().then(function(results) {
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
        entity.url = '/page/' + results[i].get('pagePermaLink');
        entity.changefreq = 'monthly';
        entity.priority = 0.7;
        entities.push(entity);
        entity = {};
      }
    }, function(error) {
      // do nothing
    });

    profileQuery.select("objectId");
    profileQuery.find().then(function(results) {
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
        entity.url = '/author/' + results[i].id;
        entity.changefreq = 'monthly';
        entity.priority = 0.6;
        entities.push(entity);
        entity = {};
      }
    }, function(error) {
      // do nothing
    });

    categoryQuery.select("categoryPermaLink");
    categoryQuery.find().then(function(results) {
      for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
        entity.url = '/category/' + results[i].get('categoryPermaLink');
        entity.changefreq = 'weekly';
        entity.priority = 0.5;
        entities.push(entity);
        entity = {};
      }
    }, function(error) {
      // do nothing
    });

    sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
      hostname: 'http://brianemilius.com',
      cacheTime: 300000,
      urls: entities
    });
    sitemap.toXML(function(err, xml) {
      if (err) {
        callback({
          error: err
        });
      }
      callback(xml);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: It might be helpful to read about [JavaScript promises](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/)

Comment: I already did and found nothing that would explain my problem. Maybe you see something I don't?

Comment: Please console.log(results). in callback.Might be you not getting the data

Comment: As I wrote in the question I already did this debugging and I am getting the results I expect to get (from parse) on all steps.

Comment: Also `results` is not in the scope of the callback function, so it's not possible to log it there. This is one of the reasons I made an array (entities) in a parent scope, so I can transport data from one function to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is starting several asynch operations then immediately taking an action that relies on their results.  We need to modify the code to wait until each operation is complete.

```
// ...
// above here from the OP 

articleQuery.equalTo('published', true);
articleQuery.select("permalink");
// hang on to the promise
var articlePromise = articleQuery.find().then(function(results) {
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
    entity.url = '/article/' + results[i].get('permalink');
    entity.changefreq = 'monthly';
    entity.priority = 0.9;
    entities.push(entity);
    entity = {};
  }
}, function(error) {
  // do nothing
});

pageQuery.select("pagePermaLink");
// hang on to the promise
var pagePromise = pageQuery.find().then(function(results) {
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
    entity.url = '/page/' + results[i].get('pagePermaLink');
    entity.changefreq = 'monthly';
    entity.priority = 0.7;
    entities.push(entity);
    entity = {};
  }
}, function(error) {
  // do nothing
});

profileQuery.select("objectId");
// hang on to the promise
var profilePromise = profileQuery.find().then(function(results) {
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
    entity.url = '/author/' + results[i].id;
    entity.changefreq = 'monthly';
    entity.priority = 0.6;
    entities.push(entity);
    entity = {};
  }
}, function(error) {
  // do nothing
});

categoryQuery.select("categoryPermaLink");
// hang on to the promise
var categoryPromise = categoryQuery.find().then(function(results) {
  for (i = 0; i < results.length; i += 1) {
    entity.url = '/category/' + results[i].get('categoryPermaLink');
    entity.changefreq = 'weekly';
    entity.priority = 0.5;
    entities.push(entity);
    entity = {};
  }
}, function(error) {
  // do nothing
});

// only after all of the promises that create entities are fulfilled
// do we execute the logic that relies on that data

var promises = [articlePromise, pagePromise, profilePromise, categoryPromise];
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
    sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
      hostname: 'http://brianemilius.com',
      cacheTime: 300000,
      urls: entities
    });
    sitemap.toXML(function(err, xml) {
      if (err) {
        callback({
          error: err
        });
      }
      callback(xml);
    });
}, function(error) {
    // handle error
});
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted. Thanks a bunch!